# C# Detect wrong visibility when subscribe to events over .NET remoting

Tags: c#, events, remoting

When subscribing to an event which is raised over remoting the callback method must be public, otherwise nothing happens when raising the event on the other side.

Is there something which helps me to detect such cases? E.g. an exception which can be forced...

Answer (score 1):

It seems, you have more a design problem, than technical. Why do you use events over remoting in the first place? It will be much more appropriate to use some mechanism, that will show to the user of your interface, that he is working with remote object, not hide this.

In this concrete example, I would declare interface for the event listener and expose methods like AddLister/RemoveLister.

So your client implements lister interface and supplies you with a remote instace which you can call when you need to raise event. This will give caller the idea, that your service is remove, and will not create problems like you have with events.

Comment: Sure this would be a possibility. But why reinvent the wheel for that purpose when the framework is capable to handle this? For example a custom FxCop rule to detect this methods would in my opinion a better alternative.

Comment: So you want your bad design to be enforced by FxCop rules? :) Well, its your choice.

Comment: Well, what other drawbacks do events over remoting have?

Comment: I just want to say, when you create a remote component, it should be clear for the users, that the component is remote. In my mind, events does not make this clear. This is not a wellknown pattern. Because of this, I would not use them. Your code should be comprehensible by anyone who reads it, not only by you.